# Wirelessly "bridge" two subnets when in range of one another

Tags: wireless-networking, dhcp, subnet, wireless-bridge

Scenario:

Subnet 1: Basic Home/Office setup with broadband internet, router, and a couple of computers.

Subnet 2: Mobile trailer with a couple of computers and a router. Sometimes its in the driveway, sometimes it isn't.

When the trailer is in the driveway, I want to be able to access the broadband internet and shared folders on computers in the Home/Office.

At the same time, when the trailer is out on a remote site, the network needs to be able to operate independently, without relying on anything that would be available to it when it was in the driveway (like the Home/Office DHCP or internet).

The only real requirement I have is that both subnets use DHCP (which I guess means DHCP needs to be turned on for both routers). The only other requirement, I ~really~ don't want to have to reconfigure anything depending on where the trailer is located. I want it to "just work" anywhere.

I'm eyeing the Ubiquiti stuff right now. It looks like a couple of Picostations might do this job. They advertise that they can be configured as an AP or a "station" (whatever the heck that means, I assume that means I can use them to connect two "locations" together). Actually, after looking through the airOS documentation, it looks like you can do darn near anything with these little guys. But since I don't know exactly what I'm doing, I can't answer this question for myself.

With my limited networking knowledge, this is the solution I see:

Home/Office: Set up DHCP to hand out IPs from 10.1.1.1 to 10.1.1.100.

Trailer: Setup up DHCP to hand out IPs from 10.1.1.101 to 10.1.1.200.

Set gateway on both DHCP servers to point to home/office router.

Configure Picostations as ____ (?) so the two separate networks become one when in range.

Am I on the right path here, or do I need to do something else?

I know enough about networking to be dangerous, but I'm certainly not a network engineer.  I'm ready to buy hardware, just didn't want to plop down money until I know I'm getting something that will do what I'm trying to accomplish.

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I got zero help here, I ended up taking the plunge and figuring it out on my own.

The Ubiquiti Picostations would have worked fine, but for my physical setup, I opted to go with a Nanostation M2 in the home/office configured as an "Access Point".  And went with a Rocket M2 in the trailer configured as a "Station".

In the home/office, I have a router configured with DHCP handing out IP addresses in the 10.1.1.100-199 range.  And in the trailer, I have a router (WAN port not used) with DHCP handing out IP addresses in the 10.1.1.50-99 range.  This way, even if the Nanostation and Rocket aren't in range of one another, I still have addresses being assigned dynamically in the trailer (just no internet of course).

This setup works great, and all computers can talk to one another (remote desktop, file sharing, etc) and access the internet no problem.

Would love to post screenshots of the setup in the airOS software to help anyone else out, but SU won't let me post images till I have more rep (sorry).